# Webpack.config.js process.env.NODE_ENV not workinkg. - ReactJS -

Tags: javascript, reactjs, webpack

I have next Webpack.config.js:

```
'use strict';

const WEBPACK = require('webpack');
const PATH = require('path');
const CopyFiles = require('copy-webpack-plugin');
const BaseName = "/upct";

const CONFIG = {
    resolve: {
        extensions: ['', '.js', '.jsx']
    },
    context: __dirname,
    entry: {
        app: ['./src/index.jsx']
    },
    /*
    output: {
        path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        /*path: './public',*//*
        publicPath: BaseName+'/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    },
    /*
    devServer: {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: PATH.join(__dirname, '/public'),
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: { 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" 
        }
    },
    */
    module: {
        loaders: [
            {
                test: /(\.js|.jsx)$/,
                loader: 'babel',
                query: {
                    "presets": [
                        "es2015",
                        "react",
                        "stage-0"
                    ],
                    "plugins": [
                        "react-html-attrs",
                        "transform-decorators-legacy",
                        "transform-class-properties"
                    ]
                }
            }
        ]
    },
    plugins: [
        new WEBPACK.DefinePlugin({
            BASENAME: JSON.stringify(BaseName),
            'process.env': {
                /*'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify(process.env.NODE_ENV)*/
                'NODE_ENV': JSON.stringify('production')
            }
        })
    ]
}

if (process.env.NODE_ENV === 'production') {
    CONFIG.output = {
        path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/publicProduction'),
        publicPath: BaseName+'/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    };

    CONFIG.plugins.push(
        new WEBPACK.optimize.UglifyJsPlugin({
            beautify: false,
            mangle: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                keep_fnames: true
            },
            compress: {
                screw_ie8: true,
                warnings: false
            },
            comments: false
        })
    );
    //babelSettings.plugins.push("transform-react-inline-elements");
    //babelSettings.plugins.push("transform-react-constant-elements");

} else {
    //CONFIG.devtool = "#cheap-module-source-map"
    CONFIG.output = {
        path: PATH.join(__dirname, '/publicDeveloping'),
        publicPath: BaseName+'/',
        filename: 'index.js'
    };

    CONFIG.devServer = {
        host: 'localhost',
        port: 3000,
        contentBase: PATH.join(__dirname, '/src'),
        inline: true,
        historyApiFallback: true,
        headers: { 
            "Access-Control-Allow-Origin": "*" 
        }
    }
    /*
    CONFIG.plugins.push(
        new webpack.HotModuleReplacementPlugin()
    );*/
}

module.exports = CONFIG;
```

and next scripts:

```
"scripts": {
    "build": "SET NODE_ENV='building' && webpack --progress --watch --colors",
    "serve": "SET NODE_ENV='testing' && webpack-dev-server --progress --colors",
    "production": "SET NODE_ENV='production' && webpack --progress -p"
  },
```

But never into in IF (when I run `npm run production`), always into in ELSE (Run the script that I run). Why could it be? (above I have declared NODE_ENV = 'production', I do not understand why it is not working...).

Thank you.

Comment: Which OS are your working in?

Comment: Windows 10. With versions: `"webpack": "^1.13.2",` and `"webpack-dev-server": "^1.15.2"`

Comment: Try `"production": "SET NODE_ENV=production & webpack --progress -p"`

Comment: I already have tried it. But it do not resolve the problem.

Comment: I think webpack config is not able to access it, try `"production": "webpack -p --define process.env.NODE_ENV='\"production\"' --progress --colors"`

Comment: I think error is in if condition due to if I run `webpack --progress -p` only (I do not modify ENV), it into in ELSE too.

Comment: I have tried it and continue failing.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I used to have the same kind of problem. Try trimming the string first and then comparing it.

```
if (process.env.NODE_ENV.trim() === 'production') {
    // Do Something
}
```

1 more thing, the `-p` flag for `webpack` and `SET NODE_ENV=production` are basically the same thing so I don't think you need them both.

Comment: Thank you. But in my case, `trim()` not solved the problem :(.

Comment: Try removing the `-p` flag and just use the following script:
`"production": "SET NODE_ENV=production && webpack"`

Comment: Yeah, I remove it. I am running next: `"production": "SET NODE_ENV='production' && webpack --progress" `

Comment: Try to console something inside the `If` statement

Comment: I tried your script. But continue failing. It could be due Webpack version?

Comment: Well, I personally use webpack 2. Their website says that webpack 1 is deprecated.

Comment: My webpack will run with v2? or I will need to change it? If not, I try to update. I have done console.log in IF and ELSE but I do not see nothing in console. (`console.log(process.env.NODE_ENV)`)

Comment: Can I help you via teamviewer or something? Well webpack 2 has some slight different configuration settings than webpack 1.

Comment: I have not installed nothing. I am on Work PC and it is not posible.. But we can start a chat here I think

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/144283/discussion-between-jumogar-and-zahid-saeed).

Answer (score 1):

You might want to try:
`SET NODE_ENV=production webpack --progress`

If you care about cross platform, you might want to try `npm` package `cross-env`.

Once you install package `cross-env`, you would change your script to look like:

Your script would change to `cross-env NODE_ENV=production webpack  --progress`

Answer (score 0):

Just another thought. 
You can try this,

```
"production": "webpack -p"
```

and in webpack config file

```
const PROD_ENV = process.argv.indexOf('-p');
```

and using ternary condition

```
...PROD_ENV ? [prod settings] : [other settings]
```

or using if condition

```
if(PROD_ENV > 0) {
  ...prod settings
} else {
  ...other settings
}
```